# How to make compiliation exception in this Java code

Tags: java

Here is checkPass method.

```
boolean checkPass(String password){
   if (password.length() > 2 && password.charAt(4) != ' ') return true;
   else return false;
}
```

password value must create exception

```
boolean password = checkPass("");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly,  you want to throw exception when the input is empty.

```
boolean checkPass(String password) throws Exception {
   if (password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
       throw new Exception("password should not be empty.");
   }
   if (password.length() > 2 && password.charAt(4) != ' ') return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Comment: No, i just need to make exception in checkPass method using this:
```
boolean password = checkPass("");
```

Comment: program needs to return not false and not true.

Comment: OK.  you can return the password directly?  then. Just adjust the logic as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to make compilation fail when it encounters code like `checkPass("")`?

I dont think that Java has static assertions, i.e assertions computed at compile time. Probably, the closest thing you can get is to use a tool like [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to statically analyze your code.

Of course, you can also use unit tests, but these are actually runtime checks (which are run just after the compilation phase, but before deploying the code to a production site).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the method return type to `void` from `boolean` and throw an `Exception` in case your condition is not satisfied.

```
void checkPass(String password) throws Exception{
   if (password.length() > 2 && password.charAt(4) != ' ') {
   //do nothing
   } else {
     throw new Exception("check pass failed");
   }
}
```

You can then use `checkPass("");` method to create an Exception.